# Mysqldump create empty sql file? [php & mysql on Windows]

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to dump a database:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "XXXX";
$dbpass = "XXXXXXXX";
$dbname = 'testdb';

$list = shell_exec ("C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.33\bin\mysqldump.exe $dbname  --user=$dbuser--password=$dbpass > dumpfile.sql");
?>
```

I tried both specified full path to mysqldump.exe or just use mysqldump, it still give me a 0kb dumpfile.sql

Details:
    Programming Language: PHP
    Database: MySql 5.XX
    OS(server): Windows Server 2003. (currently testing on Windows Vista machine)

EDIT @ Jeremy Heslop:

I tried:

```
shell_exec("C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.33\bin\mysqldump.exe --opt -h $dbhost -u$dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname > test.sql");
```

safe_mode = off

Still no luck man.

Comment: Its is mysqldump not mysqldumb :D

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19189484/1572778 it works fine.

-its about permission issue.

Answer (score 2):

Call me crazy, but don't you need to escape those backslashes in your path name?  I'm guessing that the command fails, and since the error is on stderr, nothing gets written.

Comment: i went crazy with you (removed the backslashes), nothing better, haha

Comment: That would be crazy since I was suggesting you double them :) 

shell_exec("C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.1.33\\bin\\mysqldump.exe --opt -h $dbhost -u$dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname > test.sql");

Answer (score 1):

It should be "c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin>mysqldump -u root -p zencartdb > zencartdb.sql"

it demands for password, provide if you have given password to root or simply hit enter. This will take backup successfully. I have tested it on Windows Vista also.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken the dbname should be at the end of the call after the --user and --password like this:

```
$list = shell_exec ("C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.33\bin\mysqldump.exe --user=$dbhost --password=$dbpass $dbname > dumpfile.sql");
```

Otherwise if that doesn't work there are some other things to look out for. Make sure the user that php runs as has permissions to write to that directory. Also make sure that php.ini has safe_mode = off as that could cause issues. Good luck!

Comment: Edited my answer. Is it easier to create the mysqldump in batch file?

Comment: Not if you need to pass user/pass info from php, but if you don't then a batch file might be more straight forward. When you run the mysqldump command manually from the command line does it work as expected? James answer above could be leading to something. I would also try printing out the output of $list (output of shell_exec) to se if mysqldump is returning any errors. Try turning on verbose for mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this
 $result = system ("C:\wamp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -u $username -p $password $dbname < $pathtomysqlfile");
and executed successfully then backup is restored.I'm wsing wamp.please try it..........