# mysqldump not working through php

Tags: php, command-line, mysql

I am trying to take mysqldump of database through php, i am able to take database dump through command line this way only.

```
d:
cd "d:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin"
mysqldump.exe
mysqldump --user=user --password=password --host=localhost db_name > "D:\dump\test.sql"
```

when trying to execute this command from php this way, i get a empty dump file.

```
$cmd  = 'd: cd "d:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/bin"mysqldump.exe>mysqldump --user=user --password=password --host=localhost db_name > "D:\dump\test.sql"';
exec($cmd);
```

or this way

```
$cmd  = 'd:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/bin>mysqldump.exe>mysqldump --user=user --password=password --host=localhost db_name > D:\dump\test.sql';
exec($cmd);
```

or this way

```
$cmd  = 'd:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/bin>mysqldump --user=user --password=password --host=localhost db_name > D:\dump\test.sql';
exec($cmd);
```

I get only empty dump file.
i have gone through a lot of questions here like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750531/using-a-php-file-to-generate-a-mysql-dump), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061922/mysqldump-create-empty-sql-file-php-mysql-on-windows?rq=1) and lot more, but none of that solution is working for me.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seems to use Windows, the way to create multi-command lines is to use the '&' operator ([more info](https://superuser.com/questions/62850/execute-multiple-commands-with-1-line-in-windows-commandline))

Example :

```
$cmd  = 'd: & cd "d:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/bin" & mysqldump.exe --user=user --password=password --host=localhost db_name > "D:\dump\test.sql"';
exec($cmd);
```

Also, double-check your paths because you are using `d:/wamp/...` and later `D:\dump\test.sql`, it seems that your command use slash and antislash and only `\` should work.

At last, you can debug your command using a second argument to [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) :

```
$output = array();
exec($cmd, $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: wow, that worked, didn't know how to make multi-command, thanks a lot.

Comment: also please tell me which is better to use `system($cmd)` or `exec($cmd)`.

Comment: You can have a look to [this website](http://chipmunkninja.com/Program-Execution-in-PHP%3A-exec-m@) who gives you nice explainations, or check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732832/php-exec-vs-system-vs-passthru).

Comment: if i am using `user=$username` insted if `user=user` its not working, how to make it work with username stored in variable. thanks.

Comment: this way: `...--user='.escapeshellarg($username).' --password='.escapeshelarg...` because your string is between single quotes ([more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)). Also note [escapeshellarg](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) used to protect your command against shell code injection.